# Dynamically populate a pdf

Tags: forms, pdf, populate

Could anyone help me?  I need to insert information to the header of a pdf from a customer form online with php.  I am not a programmer so I need a sense of direction before I speak to my developers.

The idea is to get licence information from a field, insert the information to the header and save the result as securely as is reasonably possible before the customised file is downloaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This will generally involve opening your existing PDF file with an appropriate PDF manipulation module (`Zend_Pdf` works for this purpose), performing whatever operations you need, such as inserting data into the document, and then outputting the document to the user with the appropriate headers (content type and disposition) set.

If you want customers to be able to download files several times, it would be wise to have the licensing information be gathered from the user account information, rather than a form.

Comment: Thanks for that Victor, I'll pass the Zend_pdf info onto my developers.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, asking for information on a particular library or tool to use is off bounds for StackOverflow (as it draws mostly opinionated answers. But even more importantly, in my experience, going to your developers and telling them which library to use while you don't know anything about it and are not a developer, is not generally a good idea. Focus on what you want to accomplish; don't worry too much about what technically is needed for them to do what you want. That's their job.

Looking at your question, there's a couple of things you might think about and discuss with them:

1) Taking information and adding it on top of an existing PDF file, is not the end of the world from a technical point of view. There are probably 100 or more different tools and libraries that can accomplish this in many different ways.

2) Much more technically challenging and worthy of a discussion with them is "*save the result as securely as is reasonably possible before the customised file is downloaded*". Normally, when you add information to a PDF document, it's not trivial to change it afterwards. But it's far from impossible. And if it's only a matter of removing stuff, it's even easier. A tool such as Adobe Acrobat for example will happily let you remove a bunch of text / graphics from a PDF file. If you want to prevent that, you have to at least protect your PDF document; set a number of flags in it that prevent it from being edited for example.

That's still not going to be waterproof, as these flags are supposed to be honoured by PDF processing applications. Adobe Acrobat does that and so do most other "decent" PDF applications, but it's certainly possible to circumvent this if you want it hard enough.

So, from your product management point of view, think about what *reasonably secure* means and have a discussion about that with your developers. That's probably going to get you much further than suggesting a particular library they're going to resent instantly because it comes from a non-developer :)